# seaborn husl or hsl color palette is not working: remains default black and white colors

Tags: python, matplotlib, hsl, seaborn

I am in need of a circular colormap, and came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23712207/cyclic-colormap-without-visual-distortions-for-use-in-phase-angle-plots) which describes using seaborn to import the husl system. I am trying to replicate the simple usage the example demonstrates, but I can't get my image to show up in color. It always displays in black and white (seaborn default color palette). I am working in ipython, but not in the ipython notebook. (Some seaborn functions work only in ipython notebook -- I need an answer that does not rely on that.) Specifically python 2.7.3, ipython 1.1.0.

MWE:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

fig = plt.figure()

im = np.random.random((100, 100))
with sns.color_palette("husl", 8):
    plt.imshow(im)
```

Displays:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ahKAH.jpg

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The other answer is (close to) the right solution, but it might be helpful to understand why this is happening. `sns.set_palette` and using `sns.color_palette` in a `with` statement control the matplotlib *color cycle*, (`mpl.rcParams["axes.color_cycle"]`), which is used to style plot elements when using `plt.plot`.

In contrast,`imshow` has a default *colormap*, which is both a different kind of object (one is a list of colors, the other is a continuous mapping from a scalar variable to a color) and has a different default setting (`mpl.rcParams["image.cmap"]`).

As @cphlewis notes, you can use the list of colors returned by `sns.color_palette` to make a colormap object, but I wouldn't do it quite that way. You can see why if you add a colorbar to the plot:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage import gaussian_filter
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sns.set_style("dark")

img = np.random.normal(size=(100, 100))
img = gaussian_filter(img, 3, 2)

cmap1 = mpl.colors.ListedColormap(sns.color_palette("husl"))

plt.figure()
plt.imshow(img, cmap=cmap1)
plt.colorbar()
```

[image]

Here's you're just making a colormap with 6 unique values, which will cause you to lose a lot of high-frequency information in the data. It's better to use more colors; 256 is a good number:

```
cmap2 = mpl.colors.ListedColormap(sns.color_palette("husl", 256))

plt.figure()
plt.imshow(img, cmap=cmap2)
plt.colorbar()
```

[image]

You may also want to use the `sns.husl_palette` function directly so you can control where the cycle starts and what level is used for lightness and saturation:

```
cmap3 = mpl.colors.ListedColormap(sns.husl_palette(256, .33, .85, .6))

plt.figure()
plt.imshow(img, cmap=cmap3)
plt.colorbar()
```

[image]

Comment: The seaborn `color_palette()` can invoke _entry_ and _exit_ to work as a Context, then? A context that could include `mpl.rcParams["image.cmap"]` but currently doesn't? (Great demo. Ironically, the discrete colorbar is useful for me to pick out data features.)

Comment: Yes, you could of course set the default `cmap` with a context manager -- most easily with the matplotlib `rc_context` function, though you could also use the seaborn `axes_style` color manager, as `image.cmap` is defined there --  but the seaborn color palettes and colormaps are objects with distinct purposes so it wouldn't make sense to do that inside `color_palette`.

Comment: Also since `imshow` takes a `cmap` kwarg, using a context manager instead of just passing the colormap directly to the function is overly complicated, and hence un-pythonic.

Comment: I did not know about `rc_context`! Excellent.

Answer (score 4):

```
seamap = mpl.colors.ListedColormap(sns.color_palette("husl"))

imshow(im,cmap=seamap)
```

[image]

The linked answer also works for me; apparently imshow isn't context-conscious and ax.plot is.