# Matplotlib darker hsv colormap

Tags: matplotlib, colors, hsv, color-mapping

I'm using the HSV colormap from matplotlib to plot some vector fields. Is there a way to darken or make smoother the HSV colours so they look more like this

[image]

than my original plot colours, which are too bright:

[image]

Comment: Check out the first section here: http://wiki.scipy.org/Cookbook/Matplotlib/ColormapTransformations

Comment: I think the comment above really does provide the answer here.  It would be good to write it up in an answer - I thought I'd comment first to see whether @farenorth or OP want to do it.  If not, I'll write something up, but I don't want to steal the likely upvotes you'd get ;)

Comment: I [suggested an edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8788677) to this Q. I was pretty sure it made the question more specific and clear (including MCVE code!). Anyone else care to chime in? Was my revision really too invasive?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. That link seems to be the closest answer, although the colours don't look that nice when darkened. I was mostly thinking in making the HSV colours more appealing (this is subjective but the colour wheel shows more or less the idea), but I think I didn't specify that properly in my question. I will try the answer below and see if I it works for me to accept it.

Comment: is `plt.get_cmap('rainbow')` closer to what you want?

Comment: Yeah, that looks much nicer, but I'm mapping the vector field, so I need the HSV definition in 360 degrees

Comment: Your question is very vague, and - as you noted - subjective. You keep talking 'mapping the vector field', but what I think you mean is that you are 'mapping vector direction'. A [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be helpful. Have you looked at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23712207/cyclic-colormap-without-visual-distortions-for-use-in-phase-angle-plots)?

Comment: Yes, I meant the direction, sorry for my english, I think I didn't explained myself properly. That colormap looks much nicer, I will try that but it stills requires an external plotting library as Seaborn. I initially tried to make the question short since mapping the vector directions into an HSV color palette is not very easy and my code is lengthy so it would complicate the post. I just thought that there would be an easy way to transform the HSV colormap, and the closest answer is your first suggested link. But yes, this turned into something more complex :)

Comment: I didn't know about `husl` , looks better. I think I will try this package https://pypi.python.org/pypi/husl , since I'm doing `vector direction --> HSV --> RGB` and I could use RGB to HUSL

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Introduction

Assuming you're trying to plot a pcolor image like this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y, x = np.mgrid[slice(-3, 3 + 0.05, 0.05),
                slice(-3, 3 + 0.15, 0.15)]
z = (1 - x / 2. + x ** 5 + y ** 3) * np.exp(-x ** 2 - y ** 2)
# x and y are bounds, so z should be the value *inside* those bounds.
# Therefore, remove the last value from the z array.
z = z[:-1, :-1]

fig = plt.figure(1)
fig.clf()
ax = plt.gca()
pcol = ax.pcolormesh(x, y, z, cmap=plt.get_cmap('hsv'), )
plt.colorbar(pcol)
ax.set_xlim([-3, 3])
ax.set_ylim([-3, 3])
```

Your image will be:

[image: HSV colormap.]

## Methods

I've written an alternate implementation of the [MPL cookbook `cmap_map` function](http://wiki.scipy.org/Cookbook/Matplotlib/ColormapTransformations) that modifies colormaps. In addition to support for kwargs and pep8 compliance, this version handles discontinuities in a colormap:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap as lsc


def cmap_map(function, cmap, name='colormap_mod', N=None, gamma=None):
    """
    Modify a colormap using `function` which must operate on 3-element
    arrays of [r, g, b] values.

    You may specify the number of colors, `N`, and the opacity, `gamma`,
    value of the returned colormap. These values default to the ones in
    the input `cmap`.

    You may also specify a `name` for the colormap, so that it can be
    loaded using plt.get_cmap(name).
    """
    if N is None:
        N = cmap.N
    if gamma is None:
        gamma = cmap._gamma
    cdict = cmap._segmentdata
    # Cast the steps into lists:
    step_dict = {key: map(lambda x: x[0], cdict[key]) for key in cdict}
    # Now get the unique steps (first column of the arrays):
    step_list = np.unique(sum(step_dict.values(), []))
    # 'y0', 'y1' are as defined in LinearSegmentedColormap docstring:
    y0 = cmap(step_list)[:, :3]
    y1 = y0.copy()[:, :3]
    # Go back to catch the discontinuities, and place them into y0, y1
    for iclr, key in enumerate(['red', 'green', 'blue']):
        for istp, step in enumerate(step_list):
            try:
                ind = step_dict[key].index(step)
            except ValueError:
                # This step is not in this color
                continue
            y0[istp, iclr] = cdict[key][ind][1]
            y1[istp, iclr] = cdict[key][ind][2]
    # Map the colors to their new values:
    y0 = np.array(map(function, y0))
    y1 = np.array(map(function, y1))
    # Build the new colormap (overwriting step_dict):
    for iclr, clr in enumerate(['red', 'green', 'blue']):
        step_dict[clr] = np.vstack((step_list, y0[:, iclr], y1[:, iclr])).T
    return lsc(name, step_dict, N=N, gamma=gamma)
```

## Implementation

To use it, simply define a function that will modify your [RGB colors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGB_color_model) as you like (values from 0 to 1) and supply it as input to `cmap_map`. To get colors close to the ones in the images you provided, for example, you could define:

```
def darken(x, ):
   return x * 0.8

dark_hsv = cmap_map(darken, plt.get_cmap('hsv'))
```

And then modify the call to pcolormesh:

```
pcol = ax.pcolormesh(x, y, z, cmap=dark_hsv)
```

[image: Darker HSV.]

If you only wanted to darken the greens in the image, you could do (now all in one line):

```
pcol = ax.pcolormesh(x, y, z,
                     cmap=cmap_map(lambda x: x * [1, 0.7, 1],
                                   plt.get_cmap('hsv'))
                    )
```

[image: Darken green only]