# Looping or wrapping a colormap over a given interval

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, graph, colormap

I recently ran into a problem where I wanted a cyclic colormap to be 'wrapped', for want of a better word, on a given interval. In the example below, I plot values over the interval `[-5, 5]`, and I want to repeat the colormap on each interval `[-1, 1]`. I started out by using [`matplotlib.colors.Normalize`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.Normalize.html#matplotlib.colors.Normalize), but while I intended this to normalise numbers onto the interval `[0, 1]`, numbers outside the given `vmin` and `vmax` arguments were mapped outside of this interval:

```
>>> norm = mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin=-1, vmax=1)
>>> norm(2)
1.5
```

When this value is passed to a colormap, the value returned is by default `cmap(1)`, but this can be changed by using `cmap.set_over()`/`cmap.set_under()` . However, from what I can see, this can only be set to a static color.

The unsatisfying solution I came up with was to define a function that applies my `norm` function to an array, mod 1, and then pass this as my data to `imshow()`, without the need to pass `norm` as an argument. My attempts so far are below:

**Code:**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Plot values between -5 and 5
x = np.linspace(-5,5,1000).reshape(1, -1)

# Normalize values to between -1 and 1
norm = mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin=-1, vmax=1)

# Function to apply norm cyclicly
def f(x):
    return norm(x)%1

# Use a cyclic cmap
cmap=plt.cm.hsv

# Plot image
fig, axs = plt.subplots(3, 1)

# Attempt using just cmap, no norm
axs[0].imshow(x, cmap=cmap, extent=[-5,5,0,1])

# Attempt applying norm, no application of modulus function
axs[1].imshow(x, cmap=cmap, norm=norm, extent=[-5,5,0,1])

# Correct output, applying norm%1 to data before passing to cmap
axs[2].imshow(f(x), cmap=cmap, extent=[-5,5,0,1])
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Question:**

Is there a better/built in way to loop/wrap a colormap without having to define a custom function, as in the bottom subplot?

Comment: Check the cyclic colormap in the tutorial: https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html
Also answers to this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23712207/cyclic-colormap-without-visual-distortions-for-use-in-phase-angle-plots

Comment: @anishtain4 this unfortunately does not answer the question - while these colormaps are indeed cyclic, as I state in the question I want to wrap these cyclic colormaps end-to-end. I specify cyclic colormaps in my question for the very reason that they begin and end on the same color, but this could be generalised for any cmap.

Comment: Does https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/colors/colormap-manipulation.html help?   You can probably use np.roll on the colormap RGB values

Comment: After some searching, I think your mode solution is the most elegant.

Comment: @JodyKlymak I've just had a look at this - I was able to create a new ListedColormap by modifying their example and using `newcolors = viridis(np.tile(np.linspace(0, 1, 256), n))` which works, but obviously only for known values of `n`. I'll keep perusing though! I was hoping this was a simple argument to `mpl.colours.Normalize` that I'd missed - seems not however.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An idea could be to adapt the custom norm from the [tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/colors/colormapnorms.html#custom-normalization-manually-implement-two-linear-ranges) to get a cyclic norm:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import colors
import numpy as np

class CyclicNormalize(colors.Normalize):
    def __init__(self, cmin=0, cmax=1, vmin=0, vmax=1, clip=False):
        self.cmin = cmin
        self.cmax = cmax
        colors.Normalize.__init__(self, vmin, vmax, clip=clip)

    def __call__(self, value, clip=False):
        x, y = [self.cmin, self.cmax], [0, 1]
        return np.ma.masked_array(np.interp(value, x, y, period=self.cmax - self.cmin))

x = np.linspace(-5, 5, 1000).reshape(1, -1)
cmap = plt.cm.hsv

cyclicnorm = CyclicNormalize(cmin=-1, cmax=1, vmin=-5, vmax=5)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
pcm = ax.imshow(x, cmap=cmap, norm=cyclicnorm, extent=[-5, 5, 0, 1])
plt.show()
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Nice, I didn't consider subclassing `Normalize`